# Insert Specific Dataframe Columns into Multiple MySQL Tables

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, pandas

Hope someone can enlighten me on this question. I am using Python 3.7 with pandas and MySQL 8.0 CE (using sqlalchemy and MySQLdb).

I am unsure how to insert **specific columns** from a single dataframe and insert it into **multiple MySQL tables** within the same db.

Original dataframe (df.head):

```
      date      time    price   discount
0   11/6/2019   7:10     4.56     0.25
1   11/6/2019   7:15     5.01     0.26
2   11/6/2019   7:20     4.87     0.25
3   11/6/2019   7:25     4.54     0.23
```

When I use my code (given below), it sends to 'summary' MySQL table:

```
  date      time    price   discount
11/6/2019   7:10     4.56     0.25
11/6/2019   7:15     5.01     0.26
11/6/2019   7:20     4.87     0.25
11/6/2019   7:25     4.54     0.23
```

End Goal - Insert price and discount in separate MySQL table within the same db for example:

MySQL table 1 - 'price'

```
  date      time    price   
11/6/2019   7:10     4.56  
11/6/2019   7:15     5.01 
11/6/2019   7:20     4.87 
11/6/2019   7:25     4.54
```

MySQL table 2 - 'discount'

```
  date      time   discount
11/6/2019   7:10     0.25
11/6/2019   7:15     0.26
11/6/2019   7:20     0.25
11/6/2019   7:25     0.23
```

This is my original .py code that works if I need to insert the entire dataframe into a single table called 'summary':

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import MySQLdb
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

df = pd.read_csv('pricing_1.csv')
engine = create_engine('mysql+mysqldb://root:python@localhost:3306/testdb2', echo = False)

df.to_sql(name = 'summary', con=engine, if_exists = 'append', index = True)
```

I have tried to Google before posting this question here but unfortunately couldn't find anything useful - perhaps it has to do with my understanding of how MySQL works?

Really appreciate for someone to guide me with some URL articles or theory! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Separate Discount and Price Dataframe separately .
2. `discount_df = df[['date','time','discount']]`
3. `price_df = df[['date','time','price']]`
4. `discount_df.to_sql(name = 'discount', con=engine, if_exists = 'append', index = True)`
5. `price_df.to_sql(name = 'price', con=engine, if_exists = 'append', index = True)`

In this way you can insert data into two tables.

Comment: Thanks. Is this the only way to do it? If I have, let say about a hundred columns and about 30 files to process hourly, will this method be effective in terms of speed?

Comment: Set chunk_size according to the number of rows you have in a dataframe and it would be effective in terms of speed